# parquet files protection when appending

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, parquet, aws-glue

I have a problem when I try to do ETL on large bunch of files on AWS.
The goal is to convert JSON files to parquet files. due to the size of the files I have to do it batch by batch . Let's say I need to do it in 15 batches , i.e. 15 separate runs to be able to convert all of them.

I am using `write.mode("append").format("parquet")` to write into parquet files in each glue pyspark job to do that.

My problem is if one job failed for some reason then I don't know what to do - some partitions are updated while some are not, some files in the batch have been processed while some have not. for example if my 9th job failed, I am kind of stuck. I dont want to delete all parquet files to start over, but also dont want to just re-run that 9th job and cause duplicates.

Is there a way to protect parquet files to only append new files into them if the whole job is successful?

THank you!!

Comment: Is your storage in S3 or on a drive of a virtual machine or something else?

Comment: @napoleon_borntoparty S3.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment and a similar experience I had with this problem, I believe this happens because of *S3 eventual consistency*. Have a look at *Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model* here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html.

We found that using partitioned staging `s3a` committer with the conflict resolution mode `replace` made our jobs not fail. 
Try the following parameters with your `spark` jobs:

```py
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode replace
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name partitioned
```

Also have a read about the `committers` here:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html

Hope this helps!

P.S. If all fails and our files are not too big, you can do a hacky solution where you save your parquet file locally and upload when your `spark` tasks are complete, but I personally do not recommend.